# Wrong Import of a One-To-One relationship

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have this three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [A] 
(
    [id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
    [serial] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY([id])
);
 
CREATE TABLE [B] 
(
    [id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
    [espFirmware] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    [AId] INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  
    PRIMARY KEY([id]),
    FOREIGN KEY([AId]) REFERENCES [A]([id]) 
         ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE [C] 
(
    [id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
    [testRF1] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    [batchNumber] INT NOT NULL,
    [AId] INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,

    PRIMARY KEY([id]),
    FOREIGN KEY([AId]) REFERENCES [A]([id]) 
         ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

If I'm not wrong, between `A-B` and `A-C` there is a one-to-one relationship.

Now, I have imported these three tables into my .NET project using an Entity Data Model - Code First from database.

I noticed that instead of having into the class A a single instance of B I have a collection of B. Why is this? I would like to have a single instance of B into A.

Comment: EF6 doesn't support this model. It only supports one-to-one associations with shared primary keys, i.e. the `id` fields in B and C should be FKs to A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you provided, there is indeed a one-to-one relationship between `A-B` and `A-C` since the `[AId]` columns in both tables `B` and `C` are marked as `UNIQUE`. This ensures that each record in `A` can be related to at most one in `B` and at most one in `C`.

However, EF might generate navigation properties based on the presence of foreign keys without necessarily considering unique constraints. Therefore, by default, when it sees a foreign key, it might assume there could be multiple child entities related to one parent entity.

You might need to adjust the generated code or use fluent API configurations.

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Serial { get; set; }

    public virtual B B { get; set; }
    public virtual C C { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EspFirmware { get; set; }

    public int AId { get; set; }
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TestRF1 { get; set; }
    public int BatchNumber { get; set; }

    public int AId { get; set; }
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
}
```

In addition to adjusting the entity classes, you might need to use the Fluent API in your DbContext to enforce the one-to-one relationship further:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<B>()
        .HasRequired(b => b.A)
        .WithOptional(a => a.B);

    modelBuilder.Entity<C>()
        .HasRequired(c => c.A)
        .WithOptional(a => a.C);
}
```

If the auto-generated classes aren't suiting your needs, you can adjust them (as long as you're not regenerating them and overwriting changes), or you can use Fluent API configurations to specify relationships without touching the generated classes.

Comment: Apparently you didn't test this. This doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @GertArnold Why?

Comment: See my comment below your question. The properties `AId` here are useless. This code should have been tested before posting.